# Error al instalar librerias en vue 3 con npm

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vue3

Estoy instalando la libreria de vuelidate con el comando `npm install @vuelidate/core @vuelidate/validators` pero por alguna razon que no logro entender, me estan retornando estos errores, hace unos dias me paso lo mismo cuando instale otras librerias para probar,

```
PS C:\DEV C\keyappfront> npm install @vuelidate/core @vuelidate/validators
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vue3@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.39
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.2.0" from @headlessui/vue@1.7.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@headlessui/vue
npm ERR!     @headlessui/vue@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@">= 3" from @heroicons/vue@1.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@heroicons/vue
npm ERR!     @heroicons/vue@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs, @vue/babel-preset-app, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @vuelidate/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.41
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@">= 2.5 < 2.7" from @vue/composition-api@1.7.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm ERR!     peerOptional @vue/composition-api@"^1.0.0-rc.1" from @vuelidate/core@2.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vuelidate/core
npm ERR!       @vuelidate/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

PS C:\DEV C\keyappfront>
```

por otra parte este es mi package.json que tengo, honestamente no entiendo que clase de error es esto, si me pide si o si actualizar algunas librerias o son problemas en las librerias instaladas!

```
{
  "name": "vue3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.0.0",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.1",
    "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "vee-validate": "^4.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

no se si sea recomendado eliminar la carpeta node_modules y reinstalar npm install o existe una forma mas sencilla y correcta de resolver estos problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema logre solucionarlo cambiando el nombre de la app, la verdad que fue algo bastante rebuscado pero al parecer el nombre chocaba con alguna libreria o package que tiene el mismo nombre en npm

de

```
{
  "name": "vue3",
}
```

a

```
{
  "name": "nuevonombre",
}
```

La verdad que fue algo muy tonto de mi parte, pero lo solucione.